# Authentication/ Authorization signup though Google account

Tags: api, authentication, authorization

When I download an app and want to sign up using your Google account. What happens exactly in the back-end between me as a user, the app, and Google in order to allow me to sign up with my existing Google account? What type of authentication/authorization would this be considered?

What happens exactly in the back-end between me as a user, the app, and Google in order to allow me to sign up with my existing Google account?